# Customer behaviour prediction when there are no negative examples

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, data-science

Imagine you own a postal service and you want to optimize your business processes. You have a history of orders in the following form (sorted by date):

```
# date   user_id   from      to               weight-in-grams
Jan-2014 "Alice"   "London"   "New York"        50
Jan-2014 "Bob"     "Madrid"   "Beijing"         100
...
Oct-2017 "Zoya"    "Moscow"   "St.Petersburg"   30
```

Most of the records (about 95%) contain positive numbers in the "weight-in-grams" field, but there are a few that have zero weight (perhaps, these messages were cancelled or lost).

Is it possible to predict whether the users from the history file (Alice, Bob etc.) will use the service in Nov., 2017? What machine learning methods should I use?

I tried to use simple logistic regression and decision trees, but they evidently give positive outcome for **any** user, as there are very few negative examples in the training set. I also tried to apply Pareto/NBD model (BTYD library in R), but it seems to be extremely slow for large datasets, and my data set contains more than 500 000 records.

I have another problem: if I impute negative examples (considering that the user, who didn't send a letter in the certain month is a negative example for this month) the dataset grows from 30 Mb up to 10 Gb.

Comment: Thank you. I will add some of my thoughts about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes you can try to predict.

You can approach this as a time series and run RNN:
Train your RNN on your set pivoted so each user is one sample.

You can also pivot your set so each user is a a row (observation) by aggregating each users' data. Then run multivariate logistic regression. You will loose information this way, but it might be simpler.  You can add time related columns such as 'average delay between orders', 'average orders per year' etc.

You can use Bayesian methods to estimate the probability with which the user will return.

Comment: What Bayesian methods do you mean?

Comment: For example Gaussian regression: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html
You will need to pivot the data in a way that is meaningful for the model.

Comment: Just read your notes on the small positive sample and the booming data-set when you pivot it with negative samples.
I think you can kill 2 birds with one stone by re-sampling. Also, if you choose to pivot the data to aggregate per user, shouldn't your data become smaller in size?

Comment: Aggregation would be very helpful, and I tried to do it,  but there are only two features at our disposal ("from" and "to"), so I'm afraid to loose some relevant info. What do you think, is it a good idea to reshape the table, so that the cities become columns rather than rows?

Comment: Not sure, I would create a categorical variable, an index, Each value of the index will mean a certain pair of cities.

Comment: Thank your for your comments. They are relly enlightening; I have to think them out.